# Can NMDS be used to check for linearity of data by comparing Eucladion - BrayCurtis ordination results?

Tags: r, statistics, multivariate-testing

I want to do a PCA (in R) but I dont know if my data is linear. I conducted an NMDS for Eucladian and Bray-Curtis distance. After removal of 1 variable with many zeros, the NMDS plots are roughly equal.

My assumption is that linear data plotted in non-linear ordination space (Bray-Curtis) results in similar results as linear data plotted in linear ordination space (Euclidian). Is this assumption justified?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For decision about linearity/unimodality of data try to use `decorana` function from `vegan` package to construct DCA and check length of axis [as recommended here](http://www.davidzeleny.net/anadat-r/doku.php/en:ca_dca).